# Get Accurate steps in google fit

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Need to get the accurate steps in google fit android, that how can we get the real steps in google fit if possible, how can we make the progress.

real steps max accuracy, using location are how to filter those steps to calculate.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Google fit works on [Step Detector](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor#TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR) sensor. Step detector does not give any value for the initial few meters because it observes the sensitivity and patterns first and then emits values.

To increase step counting accuracy, you should integrate [Accelerometer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor#TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) sensor with the Step Detector in a way that if the Step Detector is not giving any value, then take values from the Accelerometer.